# AngularJS nested ng-repeat filter multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

long time lurker, first time poster. Really love the community you have over here :)

Ok right to the problem. The goal is filtering the ng-repeat by passing 2 arguments to the filter.

I have a nested ng-repeat and on the second repeat i need to filter the entries depending on whether their lifespan in in the current month or not.

I have done this before with ng-if, but since i use different CSS for odd and even rows, that produced unwanted results.

the relevant HTML part:

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="month in monthTable">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <h2>
   <span>{{ month.start | amDateFormat:"MMMM" | uppercase}}</span>
  </h2>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div ng-class-even="'calendar_row_even'" ng-class-odd="'calendar_row_odd'"
ng-repeat="bed in syncData.beds | filter: filterListItems(month, bed) |
orderBy:'timeFrom'">
   // --> displays the unfiltered results for each month at the moment...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The monthTable is used to determine the start and endpoints of a month + to generate names is appropriate locale, it's filled like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  $scope.monthTable.push({
    start: new Date(Date.UTC($scope.currentYear, i, 1)).getTime(),
    end: new Date(Date.UTC($scope.currentYear, i+1, 1)).getTime()
  })
};
```

Pretty self-explanatory so far.

Now here is the function that "should do" the filtering:

```
$scope.filterListItems = function (month, bed) {
  console.log(month);
  console.log(bed);
  return true;
  /*return (bed.timeFrom < month.end && bed.timeUntil >= month.start);
--> this should be the code.*/
};
```

The problem is i can't get the filter to recieve 2 arguments.
If i write is this way:

```
"filter: filterListItems(month, bed)"
```

the month gets passed on, but the bed is undefined

If i write it this way:

```
"filter: filterListItems:month:bed"
```

only the bed gets passed on, but the month is undefined

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong, would really appreciate it if any1 can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your method as filter :

```
angular.module('yourApp')
    .filter('filterListItems', filterListItems);
```

And adapt your method like follows :

```
function filterListItems() {
    return function(items, month) {
        // 'items' represent the objects listed by your ng-repeat
        // Now, filter the items to return only items that respect your condition.
        return items.filter(function(item) {
            return (item.timeFrom < month.end && item.timeUntil >= month.start);
        });
    }
}
```

And use it like :

```
ng-repeat="bed in syncData.beds | filterListItems:month
```